# How do I delete a CiviCRM instance?

Tags: wordpress, installation, multisite

Trying to find details on how to remove a CiviCRM test data setup I've created.  I'm using Wordpress 5.3.2 multisite and CiviCRM 5.22.1.   I've installed CiviCRM into the plugin directory which appears to work...

.. as I installed a CiviCRM instance in one of the domains.  The installation used my default Wordpress database, and I'd prefer to do it again, but using a new database (and also in a different domain).

I'd like to have two instances, using the same code, but ideally accessing different databases for the CiviCRM data.

Anyway can't see any documentation on how to to remove the CiviCRM database and get to the position where I can reinstall in the two domains. Any suggestions on how to remove the CiviCRM database - and if this is documented anywhere?

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are easy enough to get rid of - just delete .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm and best to clear ../wp-content/uploads/civicrm as well.

For the database, you could just leave the old version there or you can use phpMyAdmin to delete all the tables starting civicrm_ leaving all the ones starting wp_ there.

Mick

Comment: And check the Sys Admin Guide for information: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP I did read the sysadmin documentation - as far as I see it doesn't appear to include information on how to uninstall.  Might be good to add it...

Comment: @David Brown feel free :-) It is open source so the documentation is produced by all of us in our spare time.....